# Trigger a webhook every time something merge into master - GitHub Webhooks

Tags: github, github-api, githooks

I not sure exactly how this will work, but I am looking to run a bash script that updates master every time something merges into master through `Github`. Is there a GitHub webhook that could be triggered on a PR merge? Also, I am not sure how would I update master through this web hook? Or any other suggestions how this could be done? I don't know if I am heading in the right direction.

By `updating master`, I meant, pull everything from master. Run a bash script that makes few changes and push new changes back to master.

Comment: listen for https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent and check of `ref  === refs/head/master` ?

Comment: yes, you are right +1. I am still not sure how would I update master through the web hook :/

Comment: You would need a server that receive the payload from webhook, has a token/credential that allow it to push to the repo, and do your logic in that server

Comment: you are right. Would you able to summarize all this as an answer below?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [GitHub webhook `push` event](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) would be useful in this case. You would need an server/application to listen for the hook, e.g. a node.js/php server, or CI services.

In your server, check the webhook payload for `ref === refs/head/master` i.e.`master` branch, or other conditions you see fit. Then to modify the repo's `master` branch, run a local `git` command or call GitHub API with proper credentials.

P.S. Updating the `master` branch with this service would also trigger a webhook event, so maybe you want to check for `pusher` too in this case.